# Error Creating Folder in Sharepoint using REST API C#

Tags: c#, .net, api, rest, sharepoint

I can accomplish all other tasks with the rest API, like uploading and downloading files, navigating through the file directory. I just keep getting either 400 Bad Request or sometimes with some tries I'll get 500 Internal Server Error. Also, I can create the request on postman and its successful

this is what the request should look like the rest is me creating it in c#

```
POST https://{site_url}/_api/web/folders
Authorization: "Bearer " + accessToken
Accept: "application/json;odata=verbose"
Content-Type: "application/json"
Content-Length: {length of request body as integer}
X-RequestDigest: "{form_digest_value}"

{
  "__metadata": {
    "type": "SP.Folder"
  },
  "ServerRelativeUrl": "/document library relative url/folder name"
}
```

private async Task PostFolderSharePoint(string url, string serverRelativeUrl)
{

```
        string accessToken = GetAccessToken().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
        string jsoncontent = JsonConvert.SerializeObject("{\"__metadata\": {\"type\": \"SP.Folder\"},\"ServerRelativeUrl\": serverRelativeUrl}");
        var content = new StringContent(jsoncontent, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
        var FormDiGestValue = await GetFormDigestValue(accessToken);

        _httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", accessToken);
        _httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
        

        var requestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post,url) { Content = content };
        requestMessage.Headers.Add("X-RequestDigest", FormDiGestValue);


        HttpResponseMessage response = await _httpClient.SendAsync(requestMessage).ConfigureAwait(false);

        return response;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I create a folder with the Sharepoint REST API:

```
public async Task<string> CreateFolder(string folderName, string relativeUrl)
{
    try
    {
        var url = "https://your.sharepoint.com/sites/devsite/_api/web/folders";

        var json = "{\"ServerRelativeUrl\": \"" + relativeUrl + "/" + folderName + "\"}";
        var payload = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("accept", "application/json;odata=verbose");
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("X-User-Agent", "spoc");
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken);
        var response = await client.PostAsync(url, payload);
        return await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    }
    catch (WebException we)
    {
        throw new SomethingException(we);
    }
}
```

and to use it:

```
var modFolder = await spocRest.CreateFolder("MOD1", "Shared Documents");
```